# Error Opening Emulator i am using flutter project emulator not connected in android studio

Tags: flutter, emulation

Error Opening Emulator
emulator: ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature.
Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature
in android studio i am using flutter project showing this error even when i use android project emulator is connected

Answer (score 0):

try deleting your emulator and reinstalling it. If no emulator is running.